# ElementTree findall 'or' operator

Tags: python, elementtree

If I have an xml file like this:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <prop>something</prop>
  </item>
  <test>
    <prop>something</prop>
  </test>
  <test2>
    <prop>something</prop>
  </test2>
</root>
```

I can use 
`xmlTree.getroot().findall("item")`
to get all of the 'item' elements.

How would I get all of the 'item' OR 'test' elements? I want something like:

`xmlTree.getroot().findall("item or test")`

I didn't see anything like this in the examples in the documentation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) from stdlib provides *only limited xpath support*, you can use `|` xpath OR operator only if you are using `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree as ET


data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<item>1</item>
<test>2</test>
</data>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

for element in tree.xpath('//item|//test'):
    print element.text
```

prints:

```
1
2
```

In case of `xml.etree.ElementTree` you can combine the results of two separate `findall()` calls:

```
for element in tree.findall('.//item') + tree.findall('.//test'):
    print element.text
```

Or, check the tag name inside the loop:

```
for element in tree.iter():
    if element.tag in ('item', 'test'):
        print element.text
```

Comment: I like the first version with the xpath. Your code works as indicated. However, I tried to change it to read the xml from a file:# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')

for element in tree.xpath('//item|//test'):
    print element.text

but I get AttributeError: ElementTree instance has no attribute 'xpath'

I also tried to just use the xpath syntax like this:

root = tree.getroot()
for element in root.findall('item|test'):
    print element.text

But nothing is output?

Comment: Ah I see the difference between the lxml and xml.etree.ElementTree now. It works like this. Are there other differences between these modules? That is, if I have other code that I've written with etree.ElementTree, will it continue to work if I change to lxml?

Comment: @DavidDoria it should, but you may have to change the code a bit, see differences [here](http://lxml.de/1.3/compatibility.html).

Answer (score 0):

### A "wild-card" solution for large data-set

Here is a solution where you do not need to specify "A | B| ...". Instead use "*" as a wild card, and filter out unwanted parts by index as shown below in the code (for example, in this question the last tag "test2" can be excluded by using lst[:-1]).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data='''
<root>
  <item>
    <prop>something1</prop>
  </item>
  <test>
    <prop>something2</prop>
  </test>
  <test2>
    <prop>something3</prop>
  </test2>
</root>'''
root = ET.fromstring(data)
lst = root.findall('*')
for x in lst[:-1]:
    print(x.find('prop').text)
```

OUTPUT:

something1

something2