# Convert XML into Dict/JSON

Tags: python, json, xml, list, dictionary

I need to convert my XML file into the JSON.

A sample of XML script looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API 0.7.55.3 9da5e7ae">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base="2018-06-17T15:31:02Z"/>
  <node id="330268305" lat="52.5475000" lon="13.3850775">
    <tag k="direction" v="240-60"/>
    <tag k="tourism" v="viewpoint"/>
    <tag k="wheelchair" v="no"/>
  </node>
  <node id="330269757" lat="52.5473115" lon="13.3843131">
    <tag k="direction" v="240-60"/>
    <tag k="tourism" v="viewpoint"/>
    <tag k="wheelchair" v="limited"/>
  </node>
  <way id="281307598">
    <center lat="52.4934004" lon="13.4843019"/>
    <nd ref="2852755795"/>
    <nd ref="3772363803"/>
    <nd ref="3772363802"/>
    <nd ref="2852755796"/>
    <nd ref="2852755797"/>
    <nd ref="2852755798"/>
    <nd ref="2852755795"/>
    <tag k="man_made" v="tower"/>
    <tag k="tourism" v="viewpoint"/>
    <tag k="tower:type" v="observation"/>
    <tag k="wheelchair" v="yes"/>
  </way>
</osm>
```

**The code** that does the execution so far.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json

input_file = r"D:\berlin\trial_xml\berlin_viewpoint_locations.xml"

tree = ET.parse(input_file)
root = tree.getroot()

result_list = [{k: (item.get(k) if k != 'extra' else
                    {i.get('k'): i.get('v') for i in item.iter('tag')})
                for k in ('id', 'lat', 'lon', 'extra')}
               for item in tree.findall("./node") + tree.findall('./way')]

print(result_list)
```

With the assistance of some Stackoverflow gurus, I have already achieved a half-done result. However, I still need to understand how to:

1. Append coordinates, that are hidden in `<center lat="52.4934004" lon="13.4843019"/>` in the same `result_list for``nodes.
   It works for`'id'` as was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560862/elementtree-findall-or-operator).
2. Append all references `<nd ref="2852755795"/> <nd ref="3772363803"/>`, the same way as was done for `extra`, e.g. nested list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the current code is not working for you is that data structures are not the same. I would suggest independent parsers for each of the `node` and `way` types. You are already parsing the `node` types so to parse the `way` a fairly simple loop can be constructed like:

```
way_list = []
for item in tree.findall("./way"):
    # get the center node
    center = item.find('center')

    # get the refs for the nd nodes
    nds = [nd.get('ref') for nd in item.iter('nd')]

    # construct a dict and append to result list
    way_list.append(dict(
        id=item.get('id'),
        lat=center.get('lat'),
        lon=center.get('lon'),
        nds=nds,
        extra={i.get('k'): i.get('v') for i in item.iter('tag')},
    ))
print(way_list)
```

#### Results:

```
[{
    'id': '281307598', 
    'lat': '52.4934004', 
    'lon': '13.4843019', 
    'nds': ['2852755795', '3772363803', '3772363802', '2852755796',
            '2852755797', '2852755798', '2852755795'],
    'extra': {    
        'man_made': 'tower', 
        'tourism': 'viewpoint', 
        'tower:type': 'observation', 
        'wheelchair': 'yes'    
    }
}]
```

Comment: [Stephen Rauch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7311767/stephen-rauch), yes it works. Nevertheless, I still have a small question. Where and how properly write a condition which will skip empty _extra_ tags. For instance, not to put `'extra': {}` into the final result, `{'id': '4795634783', 'lat': '52.5077119', 'lon': '13.3859320', 'extra': {}}`

Comment: just remove the `extra=` . or more likely what you want is to replace the `extra=` with `**` to flatten the dict.

Comment: But for those _extra_ which are not empty, I would like to perform this action and live them inside the dictionary. So my target not is to adapt this piece of code `k: (item.get(k) if k != 'extra' else
                    {i.get('k'): i.get('v') for i in item.iter('tag')})`

Comment: Thanks, it works, however, I am still wondering how to put these extra items into a dictionary as `'extra': {'man_made': 'tower'}`, but only for those elements for which `extra` is not empty, otherwise do not include `extra` into the dictionary `{'id': '281307598', 'lat': '52.4934004', 'lon': '13.4843019'}` instead of `{'id': '281307598', 'lat': '52.4934004', 'lon': '13.4843019', extra:{}}`. I hope I am explitly explaining my point fo view. I want something like: `if item.get('tag') == True: try {i.get('k'): i.get('v') for i in item.iter('tag')} else: continue`. So how to write it smart?

Comment: You could calc the `extra=` before the append, then `way_list[-1]['extra`] = ...` if extra has something in it.  The smart part is harder, because anytime you want exceptions in the processing pipeline, it takes more code.  I would instead generally leave the empty extra in the dict, because you then need code to take it out, and you will need further code to later process it for the is it there, is it not there case.

Comment: Thank you so much, [Stephen Rauch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7311767/stephen-rauch)